# Error al instalar paquete Shinobi en Laravel

Tags: laravel, users-roles

Tengo un problema al instalar el paquete shinobi en laravel 5.8, ustedes me pueden ayudar?

Este error me aparece, y se supone que shinobi si funciona en laravel 5.8 según su página web y documentación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EN FORMA DE TEXTO

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for caffeinated/shinobi ^5.0 -> satisfiable by caffeinated/shinobi[v5.0.0].

```
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.28
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
- caffeinated/shinobi v5.0.0 requires illuminate/support ^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4].
- don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.28, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.28].
```

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que es deseable siempre compartir el código, los errores y las salidas de ejecución como texto, que si alguien ve desde móvil o tiene algún tipo de discapacidad, la tiene más difícil para ver estas capturas.

Comment: perdon, okey....

Comment: Instala esta versión `composer require caffeinated/shinobi ^4.3`. Lo que pasa es que ya no se brinda soporte a versiones viejas de laravel. Por eso te toca instalar la ultima versión que le brindo a tu versión de laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La más nueva versión de Shinobi (5.X), ha quitado el soporte de Laravel 5, por lo que tienes que actualizar Laravel a la versión 6 o utilizar la versión 4.x de Shinobi para seguirlo utilizando.

En tu composer.json solo agrega la versión

```
"caffeinated/shinobi": "4.*"
```

Y después solo ejecuta

```
composer update
```

Con eso tendrás la versión de Shinobi que soporta la versión 5.x de Laravel.